# How to check if ajax call returns an empty array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a php script that returns a JSON encoded array. It works correctly, but I need to check if it's empty. My problem lies in the fact that it's an array of arrays. 
How can I properly check for an empty array on the server side?

**The PHP script (the important stuff)**

```
$data = array();
foreach ($results = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username !=?', [$username]) as $result) {
$name = $result['username'];
$lat = $result['lat'];
$lng = $result['lng'];
$distance = getDistance($user_lat, $user_lng, $lat, $lng);

if(withinRange($distance, $selected_distance, $selected_distance + 4)) {       
    //This is what's populated if data is available
    $data[] = array('name'=>$name, 'lat'=>$lat, 'lng'=>$lng); 
}

$response = array('data' => $data);
echo json_encode($response);
```

If data exists, it looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"name":"test_user2","lat":"35.932517","lng":"-89.905343"}]}
```

I have tried:

```
if(empty($response)
if(count($response) < 1)
```

but neither worked. Am I trying to access the wrong array? If so, how do I access the correct one to check for no data?

Comment: `$response` will never be empty, but `$response['data']` or `$data` may be.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Post that as an answer.

Comment: I figured it out, but if you wanna answer, I'll go ahead and give you the accept points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check $data, like so:

```
if(sizeof($data) === 0){echo "Empty";}
```

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what I was doing wrong. Accessing the wrong array. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`$response` will never be empty, but `$response['data']` or `$data` may be

`$response` is an array with a key named "data", so the size will always be 1.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that second part @Felippe. I should've known better.